# Multiplicative Noise to Additive Noise via Logarithmic Transformation

Tags: image, image-processing, signal-processing, logarithm, noise-reduction

In this [paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/11/10/1184), logarithmic transformation is offered to convert multiplicative noise in an image to additive noise before applying other filters.

logR(x,y) = log[O(x,y)×M(x,y)] = log{O(x,y)} + log{M(x,y)} = L(x,y) + S(x,y)

where F(x,y), L(x,y) and S(x,y) are the logarithms of R(x,y), O(x,y), and M(x,y), respectively.

However, I am confused about whether they just meant applying log transformation to the speckled image like below:

img_log = (np.log(img+1)/(np.log(1+np.max(img))))*255

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log(img+1)` is not the same as `log(img)`. Follow the equation you got. If a pixel is 0, then `log(img)` will be `-infinity` for that pixel. This is OK:

`0 * noise = 0` ==> `-infinity + log(noise) = -infinity`

If you add 1, you break the concept.

Also, no, you don’t need to scale the result of the logarithm. `log(img)` should be a floating-point image, don’t try to do complex arithmetic with integers. After filtering and back-transformation through `exp(.)`, you should have an image that is in the 0-255 range again, and can be converted to uint8, displayed, and/or saved like a regular image.